# Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText'

Tags: vb.net

Protected Sub btnAddSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddSubmit.Click
        Dim add As String

```
    add = "INSERT INTO account(firstname, lastname, uname, pass, type)" & " VALUES ('" & fname.Text & "','" & lname & "','" & username & "','" & password & "','" & type & "')"
```

An error pops up at this part "INSERT INTO account(firstname, lastname, uname, pass, type)" & " VALUES ('" & fname.Text & "

The Error: Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText'.

The program that I have to create should have the ability to add an account can someone help me? :(

EDIT:
I have manage to get it worked but however instead of recording the input in the textbox it shows System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText in the database (instead of for example Firstname: Tom it shows Firstname: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)

Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO account(firstname, lastname, uname, pass, type)" & " VALUES ('" & fname.ToString() & "','" & lname.ToString() & "','" & username.ToString() & "','" & password.ToString() & "','" & type.ToString() & "')"

SaveNames(SQLStatement)

This is what I had change

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: What are fname, lname etc....

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not reinvent the wheel. You should use an existing, proven, authentication system, such as ASP.Net Identity.  Otherwise, you will have vulnerabilities.

Comment: this is the fname lname                                          <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input runat=server id="fname" type="text" placeholder="Firstname">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mr Slacks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) says you have many problems in your single line of code above.
The lesser one is the use of Text property for an HtmlInputText control.

You should use the property [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for every HtmlInputText (fname, etc...) that you want to get its content.

For the other problems. Start reading about [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and [Parameterized queries](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/parameterized-query-and-sql-injection-attacks/) and [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity)

**EDIT** Your last edit applies the ToString() method to the instance of the HtmlInputText control and results (as expected) in the fully qualified class name.

You should apply the ToString() method to the Value property

```
  fname.Value.ToString ...... etc....
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! Last question, how can I clear the textbox after pressing the submit button?

Comment: fname.Value = "" should work, but if not, please post a new question.